# One ScrollViewer for two ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I've got 2 listbox and one scrollviewer and I want the scrollviewer to scroll the two listbox together. But i don't know how to do.. Here's my xaml :

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <ListBox Name="listboxRSSFeedItems" Width="240" Height="644" Margin="0,0,240,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Link to details" NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,30" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <ListBox Name="listboxRSSFeedItems2" Width="240" Height="644" Margin="240,0,0,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="Link to details" NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,30" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks a lot

---

Ok. I just tried to do one listbox with grid. it works fine, but how to choose which grid to add my item.
I used to add with "listboxRSSFeedItems.Items.Add(item)", but now, how can i choose the 2nd Column only.

```
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox x:Name="listboxRSSFeedItems" Width="480" Height="680">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="first" Grid.Column="0"> 
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding URL}" TargetName="_blank"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="second" Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding URL}" TargetName="_blank" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Try to have one list box with two stack panels

Comment: Do you need the ability to select items from either column, or just display them?

Comment: Just display them. Click and open web page, it works but i don't know how to choose the right column... :(

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "choose the 2nd Column only"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set height of your listBoxes.

ps: Consider layout using columns

```
    <ScrollViewer >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox x:Name="first" Grid.Column="0" />

            <ListBox x:Name="second" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It should be `RowDefinition` instead of column. He's trying to scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Set `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to "Disabled" for listBoxes. 
And it will be better using `StackPanel` for this puprose instead of `Grid`.